# No puedo crear un borde acorde con la etiqueta <ul> en html, css

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente que creo se explica mejor con el código. El mismo es:

```css
ul.header
    {
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: #F4F4F4;
     border: 1px solid #7C7C7C;
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }

    ul.header li
    {
     float: left;
     border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
       border-right: 1px solid #7C7C7C;
       color: #333;
       display: inline-block;
       padding: .3em;
       text-decoration: none;
    }

    .mi-imagen
    {
     height: 120px;
     width: 120px;
    }
```

```html
 <body>
 <ul class="header">
  <li class="col-md-4">
   <img src="imagen.jpg" class="mi-imagen">
   li con imagen
  </li>
  <li class="col-md-4">
   un li
  </li>
  <li class="col-md-4">
   otro li
  </li>
 </ul>
    </body>
```

Mi inconveniente es que el último `<li>` nunca se ajusta al tamaño del `<ul>`, entonces me queda un borde más chico y no queda bien. Me gustaría ver si alguien me puede ayudar a darme cuenta en dónde está el inconveniente o cómo hacer para solucionarlo.

Comment: Podrías agregar una imagen de cómo quieres que se vea?

Comment: @allnuck creo que el problema es tu imagen

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor revisa bien todas las herramientas que tienes para realizar una pregunta lo mejor posible. Existen dos forma de insertar código. Una de ellas sirve para insertar HTML y CSS como el que has puesto y que se puede ejecutar directamente desde la web para facilitar que te ayudemos. Te recomiendo que cambies el código que tienes pegado con la otra herramienta y pruebes con la que te digo para que veas las ventajas en vivo.

Comment: @allnuck si alguna respuesta te ayudo debes marcar como valida

Answer (score 1):

El problema es la imagen, que le estás asignando un height de 120px y a ul.header li le estás asignando un border, entonces CSS interpreta que debe de haber un li (donde está la imagen) con un border de 120px de height, y los demás li los pone tal cual, no se si me explico...

Deberías de añadir simplemente un height:120px en la clase ul.header li
Quedaría así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    ul.header
    {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #F4F4F4;
    border: 1px solid #7C7C7C;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

ul.header li
{
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #7C7C7C;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .3em;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 120px;
}

.mi-imagen
{
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="header">
    <li class="col-md-4">
        <img src="imagen.jpg" class="mi-imagen">
        li con imagen
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-4">
        un li
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-4">
        otro li
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quita el float

```
float: left;
```

El float sirve para acomodar elementos a izquierda o derecha, en tu caso ya se acomodan solos, primero uno y luego los demás.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba utilizando el siguiente css, de esta manera me muestra todos los bordes de los `<li>` del mismo tamaño:

```
ul.header
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #F4F4F4;
    border: 1px solid #7C7C7C;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    display: inline-table;
}

ul.header li
{
    /* float: left; */
    border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-right: 1px solid #7C7C7C;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .3em;
    text-decoration: none;

    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.mi-imagen
{
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
}
```